# Docker Compose : reroute requests of a container targeting specific domains and subdomains to a container

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have a docker-compose made of a webserver container that hosts a web app that sends webhooks at some points. I'm trying to get this webhooks rerouted to a postbin container on 80 port which can help me debugs webhooks emited from the first container.

My previous researchs leads to use a reverse proxy through an Nginx container but I didn't find documentation on how to achieve rerouting of requests to containers that includes paths or subdomains.

Have you any leads to share with me?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using a template like this one to achieve that. The requests made to https://subdomain.exampledomain.com will be forwarded by nginx to https://local_ip:12345

```
# nginx.subdomain.exampledomain.conf

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain.exampledomain.com;

    #  nginx should have read access to all clients certs 
    
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.exampledomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.exampledomain.com/privkey.pem;

    #ssl on;
    #listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        # local_ip is the host ip
        proxy_pass https://{{ local_ip }}:12345 ;
        proxy_redirect https://{{ local_ip }}:12345 https://subdomain.exampledomain.com;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried your solution and it does not work for me: when my WordPress server is making a post request to google.com for example, the request is not caught by the reverse proxy and goes directly to google.com. My goal is that if my WordPress container send a post request to any URL to google.com, then theses requests should be caught by the proxy and redirected to the postbin container of my docker-compose.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your problem then. the solution I described it for incoming request